# how to clear image control from local path

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a image control in wpf like this

```
<Image x:Name="Img" Source="{Binding IsAsync=True}" />
```

i set the image by fetching from a url like this

```
  Img.DataContext = ImageUrl;
```

it shows fine and when i want to clear it i just use

```
 Img.DataContext=null;
```

for the same control i have a browse button as well to select the image from local path like this

```
 BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));
 Img.Source=image;
```

now i want to clear that as well so i do

```
 Img.Source=null;
```

after that the control wont show the image from url only local images can be opened

Edit: probably i need to set the binding again after making source to null, not sure how to do that

Answer (score 1):

You are abusing bindings *horribly*. Please stop.

```
<Image x:Name="Img" Source="{Binding IsAsync=True}" />
```

Says "Bind to the data context", which isn't all that great. Bind to a *property* of your view model, something like:

```
<Image x:Name="Img" Source="{Binding Path=ImageLocation, IsAsync=True}" />
```

And then **only ever change the image using `ImageLocation`**. At the very least, only set it via the `DataContext`.

Once you set the source to a binding, you should *never* be changing it via code-behind. **Period**. Do that, and your problem will "magically" disappear, as you are doing it the *right* way now.

Answer (score 0):

To clear image control, clear image url.

`e.g imgControlName.ImageUrl = "";`